# Spring Boot Mongodb delete all on application shutdown

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

How can I delete all items of a MongoDB document on Spring Boot application shutdown or on ServletContext destroyed?

Here is the Spring Boot application file.It is not working:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DiscoveryServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.setProperty("server.servlet.context-path", "/");
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServiceApplication.class,args);
    }

    @NotNull
    @Bean
    ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ServletContextListener> myServletListener() {
        ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ServletContextListener> srb =
                new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<>();
        srb.setListener(new DiscoveryServiceServletContextListener());
        return srb;
    }


    class DiscoveryServiceServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

        Logger logger= Logger.getLogger(com.skyscanner.discovery.config.DiscoveryServiceServletContextListener.class);


        @Override
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
            logger.info("ServletContext initialized");
        }

        @Override
        public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce){
            //logger.info("RestAPI repository all items deleted");
            //Optional<RestAPI> query=repository.findById("flight-service");
            //RestAPI restAPI=query.get();

            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
            DB database=mongoClient.getDB("skyscannerDiscoveryDB");
            DBCollection collection=database.getCollection("restAPI");

            BasicDBObject query=new BasicDBObject();
            query.append("id","flight-service");
            collection.remove(query);

            logger.info("flight-service deleted");

        }
    }
}
```

In the contextDestroyed method I am trying to remove the item with id "flight-service" but it is not working.

How can I remove all items in a MongoDB database on contextDestroyed or application shutdown?

Comment: What does "not working" look like?

Comment: @duffymo The item with id "flight-service" is not deleted in MongoDB database

Comment: Could be a timing issue with the Mongo connection being closed by the time you get the servlet closed event. Have you tried listening from Spring events such as `ContextStoppedEvent`?

Comment: @Mike I changed the application.See the answer below

Comment: @freelancer86 Cool, that's the same idea has I was getting at. Hooking into the Spring lifecycle generally gives you better control over startup/shutdown sequence.

Answer (score 2):

It worked.I added the following code to Spring Boot application.Here is the application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DiscoveryServiceApplication {

    @Autowired
    private static ApplicationContext context;


    @Component
    public static class ApplicationLifecycle implements Lifecycle{

        @Autowired
        private RestAPIRepository repository;

        Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(ApplicationLifecycle.class);

        @Override
        public void start() {
            logger.info("Application start");
        }

        @Override
        public void stop() {
            logger.info("Application stop");
            repository.deleteAll();

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isRunning() {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.setProperty("server.servlet.context-path", "/");
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServiceApplication.class,args);

    }
    }
```